# Hazelcast map listener by predicate on map key

Tags: listener, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

how can i set a listener to a map which has a complex object for key and I want to listen only on changes that happens to entries with specific key parameter value.

for example i have a code similar to this:

```
private class MyListener implements EntryAddedListener<>,
        EntryUpdatedListener<KeyObject, Value> {

    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<KeyObject, Value> event) {
        processCallbaclk(event);
    }
    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent<KeyObject, Value> event) {
        processCallback(event);
    }
}

KeyObject{
       Integer id,
       String language
}

MyListener listener = new MyListener();
Predicate<KeyObject, Value> filter = equal(language, "EN");

imap.addEntryListener(listener, filter, true)
```

but when an entry with key that contains "EN" language is updated, my callback functions are not called. So I assume my predicate is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the key portion of a entry, you need to use "`__key`"

For example, "`__key.field1 > 5`".

See https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-entry-keys-with-predicates for more details.

Comment: aha ok ... so I need to use SQL like querry, is this possible also with criteria?

Comment: No, you can still use predicate, it's just a matter of personal choice. All that matter is the field name needs the "__key" prefix.